# Unconfirmed writes to ElasticSearch from ASP.NET app

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, nest

I would like to index new document in ElasticSearch and I don't care about success of the operation - but I would like it quickly, or, more precisely, I do not want it to block. I wonder if there is a way to do this using [Nest](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/) client.

There is of course possibility of doing something like `new Task(IndexAsync).Start()`, but I am afraid to do this in ASP.NET setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy to perform async index operation as under:

```
var task = client.IndexAsync(doc); // doc is the object you want to index
```

Look at [this](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/core/) for more information.